# Adjusting link paths in a Navbar PHP file for subdirectories

Tags: php, html, jquery, href, web-hosting

I'm trying to create a portfolio website. This is my third attempt, and I've been attempting to use PHP files for the first time. In my previous websites, I would copy large swaths of HTML into each page so that they would be formatted the same. With this website, I'm instead just trying to link to a few PHP files that contain code shared by multiple pages, like the navigation bar for instance.

My issue is this. Say in my index file

```
mywebsite/index.php
```

I include this PHP file which contains HTML code for a navigation bar

```
<?php
echo <<<EOT

    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <div id="nav">
        <a class="nav-link" id="index-link" href="">About</a>
                <div class="nav-divider"></div>
        <a class="nav-link" id="resume-link" href="resume">Resume</a>
                <div class="nav-divider"></div>
        <a class="nav-link" id="portfolio-link" href="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                <div class="nav-divider"></div>
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-link" href="contact">Contact Me</a>
    </div>

EOT;
?>
```

However, the way the links work, if I wanted to include this same navigation bar in a sub-directory webpage

```
mywebsite/portfolio/index.php
```

All of the links would stop working.

I've tried doing absolute paths to the root, but then the webpage's url shows the absolute path as well, including things public_html in the url which looks bad.

I've tried doing paths like "mywebsite.com/..." and "mywebsite/..." but thats just shows up as "mywebsite.com/mywebsite/..." and doesn't actually work. If I try saying "public_html/..." public_html becomes included in the url.

**I don't want to create a second PHP file just to have the same code with slightly different href paths. Is there a path I could use for both my main directory and subdirectories that doesn't show up weird in the url? If not, is there a way to use Javascript or Jquery to detect if a file is in a subdirectory, and add "../" to all links inside the included PHP files?**

I can't seem to find an answer to this question, maybe I'm not using the right words in my searches? This feels like it would be a common issue.

Comment: Use a slash `/` in front of your links: `href="/resume"` This uses the topmost/DocumentRoot of your server

Comment: i thought a single `/` meant the current directory, not the topmost? maybe that's my own misconception? if i link to `href="/resume"` inside `/portfolio/index.php` will it still work?

Comment: `./` is the current, `../` the parent, `/` "the root".